# How to set a ScrollViewer's HorizontalOffset and ScrollToHorizontalOffset in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm having hard time figuring out how to set `HorizontalOffset` and `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` of a `ScrollViewer`. I need to set them for an animation in a `StoryBoard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I note that you tagged Windows 8 (Metro/WinRT?) so while the answer below seems related to WPF, it might work or at least give you some ideas.

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/how-to-set-wpf-scrollviewer-verticaloffset-and-horizontal-offset/

Comment: Hey Colin, this is what I was looking for. I tried to implement it in my Windows 8 Metro app, but I'm unable to use `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In Metro use PropertyMetadata instead

Comment: Oh my! I'd have hugged you if you were here. I can't thank you enough, Colin! :D

Answer (score 4):

```
  scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(h);
  scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(v);
```